# How to toast a simple message when you walk into a Geofence?

Tags: android, android-location, geofencing, android-geofence, android-gps

So im completely new to geofences, and I followed the following tutorial on setting up geofences: http://io2015codelabs.appspot.com/codelabs/geofences#4 .

The code ran, but when I walk into a geo fence nothing happens... How would i toast something as I enter or leave a geofence? My code is exactly like the one in the guide. So I hope you guys can help me with some example. I

here is geo fence class:

```
public class GeoFence extends AppCompatActivity implements
        GoogleApiClient.ConnectionCallbacks,
        GoogleApiClient.OnConnectionFailedListener,
        ResultCallback<Status>
{
    protected ArrayList<Geofence> mGeofenceList;
    protected GoogleApiClient mGoogleApiClient;
    private Button mAddGeofencesButton;

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
    {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_geo_fence);
        mAddGeofencesButton = (Button) findViewById(R.id.add_geofences_button);
        // Empty list for storing geofences.
        mGeofenceList = new ArrayList<Geofence>();

        // Get the geofences used. Geofence data is hard coded in this sample.
        populateGeofenceList();

        // Kick off the request to build GoogleApiClient.
        buildGoogleApiClient();

    }

    public void populateGeofenceList() {
        for (Map.Entry<String, LatLng> entry : Constants.LANDMARKS.entrySet()) {
            mGeofenceList.add(new Geofence.Builder()
                    .setRequestId(entry.getKey())
                    .setCircularRegion(
                            entry.getValue().latitude,
                            entry.getValue().longitude,
                            Constants.GEOFENCE_RADIUS_IN_METERS
                    )
                    .setExpirationDuration(Constants.GEOFENCE_EXPIRATION_IN_MILLISECONDS)
                    .setTransitionTypes(Geofence.GEOFENCE_TRANSITION_ENTER |
                            Geofence.GEOFENCE_TRANSITION_EXIT)
                    .build());
        }
    }
    protected synchronized void buildGoogleApiClient() {
        mGoogleApiClient = new GoogleApiClient.Builder(this)
                .addConnectionCallbacks(this)
                .addOnConnectionFailedListener(this)
                .addApi(LocationServices.API)
                .build();
    }
    public void addGeofencesButtonHandler(View view) {
        if (!mGoogleApiClient.isConnected()) {
            Toast.makeText(this, "Google API Client not connected!", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            return;
        }

        try {
            LocationServices.GeofencingApi.addGeofences(
                    mGoogleApiClient,
                    getGeofencingRequest(),
                    getGeofencePendingIntent()
            ).setResultCallback(this); // Result processed in onResult().
        } catch (SecurityException securityException) {
            // Catch exception generated if the app does not use ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION permission.
        }
    }
    private GeofencingRequest getGeofencingRequest() {
        GeofencingRequest.Builder builder = new GeofencingRequest.Builder();
        builder.setInitialTrigger(GeofencingRequest.INITIAL_TRIGGER_ENTER);
        builder.addGeofences(mGeofenceList);
        return builder.build();
    }
    private PendingIntent getGeofencePendingIntent() {
        Intent intent = new Intent(this, GTIS.class);
        // We use FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT so that we get the same pending intent back when calling addgeoFences()
        return PendingIntent.getService(this, 0, intent, PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT);
    }
    @Override
    public void onConnected(Bundle connectionHint) {

    }

    @Override
    public void onConnectionFailed(ConnectionResult result) {
        // Do something with result.getErrorCode());
    }
    @Override
    public void onConnectionSuspended(int cause) {
        mGoogleApiClient.connect();
    }
    @Override
    protected void onStart() {
        super.onStart();
        if (!mGoogleApiClient.isConnecting() || !mGoogleApiClient.isConnected()) {
            mGoogleApiClient.connect();
        }
    }

    @Override
    protected void onStop() {
        super.onStop();
        if (mGoogleApiClient.isConnecting() || mGoogleApiClient.isConnected()) {
            mGoogleApiClient.disconnect();
        }
    }

    public void onResult(Status status)
    {
        if (status.isSuccess()) {
            Toast.makeText(
                    this,
                    "Geofences Added",
                    Toast.LENGTH_SHORT
            ).show();
        } else {
           Toast.makeText(this,"No geo fence :(",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }
    }
}
```

Here is the GeofenceTransitionsIntentService class

```
public class GTIS extends IntentService
{
    protected static final String TAG = "GeofenceTransitionsIS";

    public GTIS() {
        super(TAG);  // use TAG to name the IntentService worker thread
    }

    @Override
    protected void onHandleIntent(Intent intent) {
        GeofencingEvent event = GeofencingEvent.fromIntent(intent);
        if (event.hasError()) {
            Log.e(TAG, "GeofencingEvent Error: " + event.getErrorCode());
            String description = getGeofenceTransitionDetails(event);
            sendNotification(description);
            return;
        }
    }
    private static String getGeofenceTransitionDetails(GeofencingEvent event) {
        String transitionString =
                GeofenceStatusCodes.getStatusCodeString(event.getGeofenceTransition());
        List triggeringIDs = new ArrayList();
        for (Geofence geofence : event.getTriggeringGeofences()) {
            triggeringIDs.add(geofence.getRequestId());
        }
        return String.format("%s: %s", transitionString, TextUtils.join(", ", triggeringIDs));
    }

    private void sendNotification(String notificationDetails) {
        // Create an explicit content Intent that starts MainActivity.
        Intent notificationIntent = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), Geofence.class);

        // Get a PendingIntent containing the entire back stack.
        TaskStackBuilder stackBuilder = TaskStackBuilder.create(this);
        stackBuilder.addParentStack(GeoFence.class).addNextIntent(notificationIntent);
        PendingIntent notificationPendingIntent =
                stackBuilder.getPendingIntent(0, PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT);

        // Get a notification builder that's compatible with platform versions >= 4
        NotificationCompat.Builder builder = new NotificationCompat.Builder(this);

        // Define the notification settings.
        builder.setColor(Color.RED)
                .setContentTitle(notificationDetails)
                .setContentText("Click notification to return to App")
                .setContentIntent(notificationPendingIntent)
                .setAutoCancel(true);

        // Fire and notify the built Notification.
        NotificationManager notificationManager =
                (NotificationManager) getSystemService(Context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);
        notificationManager.notify(0, builder.build());
    }

}
```

Here is my constants class:

```
public class Constants
{
    public static final long GEOFENCE_EXPIRATION_IN_MILLISECONDS = 12 * 60 * 60 * 1000;
    public static final float GEOFENCE_RADIUS_IN_METERS = 20;

    public static final HashMap<String, LatLng> LANDMARKS = new HashMap<String, LatLng>();
    static {
        // San Francisco International Airport.
        LANDMARKS.put("Westwood", new LatLng(34.067313, -118.461164)); //34.065767, -118.459658  LANDMARKS.put("Westwood", new LatLng(34.065767,  -118.459658));

        // Googleplex.
        LANDMARKS.put("Japantown", new LatLng(37.785281,-122.4296384));

        // Test
        LANDMARKS.put("SFO", new LatLng(37.621313,-122.378955));
    }
}
```

Comment: Follow the next step, and show the toast in `onHandleIntent` somewhere.

Comment: @stkent so I just write a simple Toast statement in onHandleIntent?

Comment: I mean i implemented the onHandleIntent the way the guide did it and nothing happened...?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The code in the guide shows a `Notification` not a `Toast`. It's not working for you because you are calling `sendNotification()` inside the `if(event.hasError())` statement which is not triggered in your case because no error happens

What you need to do is:

```
@Override
protected void onHandleIntent(Intent intent) {
    GeofencingEvent event = GeofencingEvent.fromIntent(intent);
    if (event.hasError()) {
        Log.e(TAG, "GeofencingEvent Error: " + event.getErrorCode());
    }
    String description = getGeofenceTransitionDetails(event);
    sendNotification(description);
}
```

Again, this code would show a `Notification` which would make more sense than a `Toast` in a real life app for these reasons:

1. Your app may not even be active at the time of the Geofence transition and a Toast just showing out of nowhere may look weird to the user.
2. A notification allows you to show more info (title and text) and maybe direct back to your app
3. It gives the user the chance to read and dismiss it at their convenience

If you still want to show a `Toast` anyway, you should do it the same way you would do it in an `Activity` ([`IntentService`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/IntentService.html) is a `Context` too):

```
Toast.makeText(this, description, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
```